# Javascript Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have cookies for the domain `.forum.mywebsite.com` and for `.mywebsite.com`.

Is it possible to read the cookie for the `.mywebsite.com` domain with javascript from the `forum.mywebsite.com` location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should be able to read it. Check the following articles

> When the JavaScript set cookies
>   process is invoked, the script either
>   presents the browser with a domain, or
>   a blank value. If no domain is given
>   it is assumed to be the domain of the
>   page i.e.
>   java-programming.suite101.com in this
>   case.
>
> The JavaScript cookies path, on the
>   other hand, allows the programmer to
>   make sure that the cookie is only
>   valid (sent to the server) for pages
>   in a specific path on the website. So,
>   specifying a path such as /blog would
>   restrict the cookie to
>   my.domain.com/blog. If the cookie
>   should be applicable across the whole
>   (sub)domain, then path=/ should be
>   specified.

1. [Javascript Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
2. [Using Javascript Cookies](http://java-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/using_javascript_cookies_with_html)

But you will not be able to delete the cookie from the subdomain. Check this question in SO : [Is it possible to delete subdomain cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117240/is-it-possible-to-delete-subdomain-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the domain which has access to a given cookie via adding the cookie attribute value

```
domain={domainname};
```

If *{domainname}* starts with a leading `.`, any subdomain may access the cookie as well (source: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)).

According to [RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt), which is referenced by the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038), the leading `.` shouldn't be necessary, but better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: but i'm on the subdomain and i'd like to access the top domain cookie.
i've tried document.cookie, but the top-domain cookies aren't there.

Answer (score -3):

The cookie is sent to the server as part of the request, it's not something that's accessible from the client as far as I'm aware (therefore not accessible to javascript).

Comment: JavaScript can access cookies, so long as HttpOnly is not set.