# how to setCookie and getCookie using domain name

Tags: javascript, cookies

when i save cookie, it stored with the current URL link., also when i get cookie that search for the current URL only. i need to save and retrieve cookies with my own defined URL links. can you help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362256/javascript-cookie), among others

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read cookies set by different domains. That would be a horrific security problem if it was possible.

Comment: @saran: yes that is possible, because they are on the same domain ("sample"). I think you should edit the title of your question if that is the case.

Comment: @Crescent I think "sample" is a directory here. The OP's question could be "how to read cookies set in a different directory on the same domain" - don't know

Comment: @saran wrap: you intentionally prefixed your sample links with "http://", which confuses the issue. Please address!

Comment: The question title explicitly says "domain"