# getCookie using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to setCookie and getCookie using domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404723/how-to-setcookie-and-getcookie-using-domain-name)

when i getcookie using javascript, that will get for the current URL.

i want to getCookie by passing domain name, how to get it?

Comment: [You already asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404723/how-to-setcookie-and-getcookie-using-domain-name).

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to query cookies set for a different domain? That can't be done for security reasons.

Imagine the implications: Any site could fetch the user's session cookies for their online banking site, or almost any other site they are logged into.

Comment: @saran: are you sure "domain" is the right word? Those two sample links are on the same domain, so yes it would be possible.

Comment: can you please send some code to save and retrieve cookies by giving URL names for my problem?