# Php can't delete cookie ( Secure Cookie )

Tags: php, cookies, dns, subdomain

I am using to set cookie on user login

```
$a = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', 'domain.com');
$b = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', 'www.domain.com');
$c = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', '.domain.com');
```

But I can't delete cookie

I tried

```
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.domain.com',true);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'domain.com',true);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'www.domain.com',true);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'',mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'test.domain.com',true);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'',mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.www.domain.com',true);

setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.domain.com',false);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'domain.com',false);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'www.domain.com',false);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'test.domain.com',false);
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'',mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.www.domain.com',false);


setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.domain.com');
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'domain.com');
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'www.domain.com');
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', 'test.domain.com');
setcookie($this->remCookieName,'',mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), '/', '.www.domain.com');

setcookie($this->remCookieName,'', mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990));

setcookie($this->remCookieName,NULL,mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990));

unset($_COOKIE[$this->remCookieName]);
```

But I cant delete my cookie

If if I set secure cookie like this

```
$a = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', 'domain.com',TRUE);
$b = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', 'www.domain.com',TRUE);
$c = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', '.domain.com',TRUE);
```

I can delete but if user loged in domain.com and join to www.domain.com he was not login

or He loged in www.domain.com, he was not login domain.com

he was login www.domain.com or domain.com, i want to user login www.domain.com and domain.com

sorry my english :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delete subdomain cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117240/is-it-possible-to-delete-subdomain-cookies)

Comment: Now When I was create any subdomain or in root domain, I can acess any subdomain or root domain But ı cant delete

`$c = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', '.domain.com');`

But When I set cookie secure SET = TRUE 

`$c = setcookie($this->remCookieName,$cookie, time() + $this->remTime, '/', '.domain.com',TRUE);`

I can Delete but I cant access any sub domain.


I want to my cookie accessable any subdomian or root domain, and i want to delete :)

Comment: I solved my problem, You must havent sent header before set cookie :) I used ob_start() and my problem solved

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, You can't send header before you set cookie.

I used ob_start() and that solved my problem