# How to clear cookies at both parent and subdomain in java?

Tags: java, cookies

Hi i have a site which iframes a login/register form. Now on submission of this form cookies are set from the subdomain and on logout they are cleared. Cookies are set for both parent domain and subdomain. For clearing the cookie after a lot of googleing I found solution in the methods given in [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet). It is working fine but I am still having issue for clearing cookies for subdomain. I would really appreciate if anyone has faced such situation and knows  answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117240/is-it-possible-to-delete-subdomain-cookies

Comment: Thanks. I went through this question. In my case, Cookie domain is set as .domain.com, for it to be accessible across subdomains. Cookies are set and cleared at subdomain. But only the parent domain cookies are cleared and not sub domain ones.